# Ktor: delete temporary file after response is sent

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I'm sending a temporary file as a response to a request using the ktor library on a android tablet, but I can't find a way to safe delete it after being sent (or something went wrong).

How can I make sure that this file was delete without interrupting the sending process? Maybe using some callback or method that I´m not aware of.

**Update: answering comments:**

my code:

```
try {
    call.response.headers.append("entity-count", entityCount)
    call.response.headers.append("sync-length", lenght)
    call.respondFile(FileContent(file) // need to delete this file after sent OR failed
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, e)
}
```

should I just add a file.delete() line inside a finally block?

I think my main question/confusion (coming from java world) its if respondFile is a blocking call or not. If it its, just adding `file.delete` on finally block will be fine, otherwise I need to register somme kind of onCompleted callback.

Comment: What do you mean by "without interrupting the sending process"? You send data using coroutines: when this suspend function finishes processing returns control and goes the the next line (or throws an error), this means you can clear your resources.

Comment: If you use `ApplicationCall.respondFile` then a file will be closed at the end of a sending process. Could you please update your question with a code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `finally`: it will be called after sending the file or in case of an error

```
try {
    call.response.headers.append("entity-count", entityCount)
    call.response.headers.append("sync-length", lenght)
    call.respondFile(FileContent(file) // need to delete this file after sent OR failed
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, e)
} finally {
    file.delete()
}
```